# What comic run is Bruce Wayne fighting for 28 hours in the pit?

Tags: dc, batman, episode-identification

What is the issue where Bruce Wayne fights for 28 hours in the pit?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Downvoted for lack of research, it’s the first result when Googling the title.

Answer (score 2):

*[Batman Volume 2 #23](https://comicnewbies.com/2019/10/25/bruce-wayne-in-a-norway-death-match/)*

> Bruce Wayne, during his early years of training, fought inside a Norway death-match pit for 28 hours straight. The facilitator is trying to get Bruce to kill someone in order to end the match, the former refuses to do so. In the end, his gritty determination wins and the rest of the fighters refuse to enter the pit due to their fear of the “demon” inside.